# creating RadioButton in TableView Column

Tags: javafx, tableview

I followed the [tutorial about TableView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) in Oracle docs, and I want to do the same thing, but instead of showing a TextField to modified items, I want to show a RadioButton.
(I created the TableView with RadionButton on it)

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? Also, if you are wanting a `RadioButton` that would imply some kind of exclusivity in terms of what is selected. Can you explain the logic a bit more?

Comment: According to @James_D normally in the TableView for select rows is used checkbox

Comment: Showing a RadioButton in a TableView is somehow a contradiction to the TableView model in: The TableView only display a view into the data table. The data table mgiht be much bugger. A RadioButton requires all related data entries to be linked to a ToggleGroup together, but what shall we do, if they are not in the current view?

Comment: I created the tableView with RadioButton on it, but what exactly I want, is that: when the application begin the users will see the data that he had entered and he will have also the possibility to modified them.
Some fields need just to be cheeked (yes/no) so he will see what he has done, and if he wants he will change the cheeked items

Comment: Just use a [`CheckBoxTableCell`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTableCell.html)

Comment: But I need RadioButton so that the user can chose just one choice

Comment: Please post some code. Your description is too hard to follow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used the tutorial at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm  (see *Editing Data in the Table*) and extended it. As a basis for the values, which should be set by radio buttons I assume an Enumeration.

In my example I extended the `Person` class with the enum `Participation` (indicating whether or not the people of the list attending an fictive event) ...

```
public static enum Participation {
    YES,
    NO,
    MAYBE;

    public String toString() {
        return super.toString().toLowerCase();
    };
}

...

public static class Person {

    private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty email;
    private final SimpleObjectProperty<Participation> participation;

...
```

I implemented a `RadioButtonCell`, which takes an arbitraty `EnumSet<T>`. So you can use it for every Enumeration and every TableColumn, which should contain RadioButtons.

```
public static class RadioButtonCell<S,T extends Enum<T>> extends TableCell<S,T>{

    private EnumSet<T> enumeration;

    public RadioButtonCell(EnumSet<T> enumeration) {
        this.enumeration = enumeration;
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty)
    {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (!empty) 
        {
            // gui setup
            HBox hb = new HBox(7);
            hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            final ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();

            // create a radio button for each 'element' of the enumeration
            for (Enum<T> enumElement : enumeration) {
                RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(enumElement.toString());
                radioButton.setUserData(enumElement);
                radioButton.setToggleGroup(group);
                hb.getChildren().add(radioButton);
                if (enumElement.equals(item)) {
                    radioButton.setSelected(true);
                }
            }

            // issue events on change of the selected radio button
            group.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>() {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> observable,
                        Toggle oldValue, Toggle newValue) {
                    getTableView().edit(getIndex(), getTableColumn());
                    RadioButtonCell.this.commitEdit((T) newValue.getUserData());
                }
            });
            setGraphic(hb);
        } 
    }
}
```

You now have to adjust the CellFactory of the particular TableColumn

```
 participationColumn.setCellFactory((param) -> new RadioButtonCell<Person, Participation>(EnumSet.allOf(Participation.class)));
```

Finally update the actual value of your data on a commit as usual:

```
participationColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, Participation>("participation"));
    participationColumn.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, Participation>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, Participation> t) {
                    ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setParticipation(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        );
```

[image: Result]

Comment: This code works, but if anyone runs into the issue of clearing the entire table, and adding different data, there is a simple fix.

after the if(!empty){....}  add this else statement:  

else
       setGraphic(null);

Answer (score 1):

gkri, thank you for the nice code! This is very useful. I have one additional remark: Of course the new SimpleObjectProperty needs its get & set methods. Without the getter the table will not properly update, especially when sorting or, with TreeTableView, when expanding or collapsing nodes:

```
public void setParticipation(Participation p){
            participation.set(p);
        }

public Participation getParticipation(){
            return participation.get();
        }
```

So the full code sample:

```
import java.util.EnumSet;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Toggle;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewSample extends Application {

    private final TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com",Participation.MAYBE),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com",Participation.MAYBE),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com",Participation.MAYBE),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com",Participation.MAYBE),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com",Participation.MAYBE));
    final HBox hb = new HBox();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(650);
        stage.setHeight(550);

        final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

        table.setEditable(true);
        table.setMinWidth(640);

        TableColumn<Person,String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));

        TableColumn<Person,String>lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));

        TableColumn<Person,String> emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");
        emailCol.setMinWidth(200);
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("email"));

        TableColumn<Person,Participation> participationColumn = new TableColumn("Participation");
        participationColumn.setCellFactory((param) -> new RadioButtonCell<Person, Participation>(EnumSet.allOf(Participation.class)));
        participationColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, Participation>("participation"));
        participationColumn.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, Participation>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, Participation> t) {
                        ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                            t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                            ).setParticipation(t.getNewValue());
                    }
                }
            );


        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol, participationColumn );

        final TextField addFirstName = new TextField();
        addFirstName.setPromptText("First Name");
        addFirstName.setMaxWidth(firstNameCol.getPrefWidth());
        final TextField addLastName = new TextField();
        addLastName.setMaxWidth(lastNameCol.getPrefWidth());
        addLastName.setPromptText("Last Name");
        final TextField addEmail = new TextField();
        addEmail.setMaxWidth(emailCol.getPrefWidth());
        addEmail.setPromptText("Email");

        final Button addButton = new Button("Add");
        addButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
            data.add(new Person(
                    addFirstName.getText(),
                    addLastName.getText(),
                    addEmail.getText(),
                    Participation.NO
                    ));
            addFirstName.clear();
            addLastName.clear();
            addEmail.clear();
        });

        hb.getChildren().addAll(addFirstName, addLastName, addEmail, addButton);
        hb.setSpacing(3);

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table, hb);

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static enum Participation {
        YES,
        NO,
        MAYBE;

        public String toString() {
            return super.toString().toLowerCase();
        };
    }

    public static class Person {

        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty email;
        private final SimpleObjectProperty<Participation> participation = new SimpleObjectProperty<Participation>();

        private Person(String fName, String lName, String email, Participation p ) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
            this.participation.setValue(p);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName) {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email.get();
        }

        public void setEmail(String fName) {
            email.set(fName);
        }

        public void setParticipation(Participation p){
            participation.set(p);
        }

        public Participation getParticipation(){
            return participation.get();
        }
    }





    public static class RadioButtonCell<S,T extends Enum<T>> extends TableCell<S,T>{

        private EnumSet<T> enumeration;

        public RadioButtonCell(EnumSet<T> enumeration) {
            this.enumeration = enumeration;
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty)
        {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (!empty) 
            {
                // gui setup
                HBox hb = new HBox(7);
                hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                final ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();

                // create a radio button for each 'element' of the enumeration
                for (Enum<T> enumElement : enumeration) {
                    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(enumElement.toString());
                    radioButton.setUserData(enumElement);
                    radioButton.setToggleGroup(group);
                    hb.getChildren().add(radioButton);
                    if (enumElement.equals(item)) {
                        radioButton.setSelected(true);
                    }
                }

                // issue events on change of the selected radio button
                group.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>() {

                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> observable,
                            Toggle oldValue, Toggle newValue) {
                        getTableView().edit(getIndex(), getTableColumn());
                        RadioButtonCell.this.commitEdit((T) newValue.getUserData());
                    }
                });
                setGraphic(hb);
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simly do it like in the example [12-8 Editing a Table Cell](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm#CJAEHEBD).
Define a `EditingCell` like there(at the bottom) but simply replace the TextField with a RadioButton.

If you need further assistance, write a comment under this answer.

Happy Coding,
Kalasch