# bind SelectProperty of RadioButton in TableView

Tags: java, javafx

I created a RadioButtonCell with this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475123/creating-radiobutton-in-tableview-column) but now i want to bind the selectedPropeties of my RadioButton with the properties contained in the ObservableList linked to this TableView. The observableList contains object type of "Risk", and the Model is containing:

```
final BooleanProperty isDefaultRiskProperty;
```

My own TableCell implementation is:

```
package utils;

import Model.databaseModels.Risk;
import controllers.risks.ModifyRisksAvailableController;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;

public class RadioButtonCell extends TableCell<Risk, Boolean> {

ToggleGroup toggleGroup;
ModifyRisksAvailableController modifyRisksAvailableController;

public RadioButtonCell(ToggleGroup group){
    toggleGroup = group;
}

@Override
public void startEdit() {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        super.startEdit();
    }
}

@Override
protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty){
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    System.out.println(item);

    if(!empty && item != null){

        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
        radioButton.setToggleGroup(this.toggleGroup);
        radioButton.setSelected(item);
        setGraphic(radioButton);

    }else{
        setGraphic(null);
    }

    }
}
```

My TableView contains 3 columns:

```
@FXML
TableColumn<Risk,Boolean> ColumnCheckBox;

@FXML
TableColumn<Risk,Number> ColumnRiskValue;

@FXML
TableColumn<Risk, Boolean> ColumnIsDefaultRisk;
```

And I initialize the TableView like this:

```
//Colonne -> Checbkox / sélection pour suppression
    ColumnCheckBox.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().checkProperty());
    ColumnCheckBox.setCellFactory(column -> new CheckBoxTableCell<>());
    ColumnCheckBox.setEditable(true);
    ColumnCheckBox.setVisible(false);
    ColumnCheckBox.setPrefWidth(24.0);

    //Colonne -> Checkbox / risque par défaut
    ColumnIsDefaultRisk.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().isDefaultRiskProperty());
    ColumnIsDefaultRisk.setCellFactory(column -> new RadioButtonCell(toggleGroup,this));
    ColumnIsDefaultRisk.setEditable(true);


    //Colonne -> TextField / % de risque
    ColumnRiskValue.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().riskValueProperty());
    ColumnRiskValue.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new NumberStringConverter()));
    ColumnRiskValue.setEditable(true);
```

The property i want to bind with the radioButton is ".isDefaultRiskProperty()" of the "ColumnIsDefaultRisk" column. I giving my datas to the column with setCellValueFactory but i can't get the SimpleBooleanProperty in my CellFactory.
The param "item" that i get in the updateItem's method is a Boolean, (it converting BooleanProperty to Boolean), but i want a ObservableValue.

Thanks you very much.

Comment: Check this answer, I think it is what you are looking for?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475123/creating-radiobutton-in-tableview-column

Comment: I have already read this answer but i didn't answer to my question. I wan to say that when i change the choosed radioButton it is not repliacted in the ObservableList of the TableView. So that's why i want to bind the ObservableList to the RadioButton controllers

Comment: this solution is creating a "java.lang.StackOverflowError".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that table cells aren’t guaranteed to exist all the time;  they are for painting and editing only.  So, a ToggleGroup isn’t really of any use here.

But you can do the work of a ToggleGroup yourself fairly easily:

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    if (!empty && item != null) {

        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
        radioButton.setToggleGroup(this.toggleGroup);
        radioButton.setSelected(item);
        setGraphic(radioButton);

        radioButton.selectedProperty().addListener(
            (o, old, selected) -> {
                if (selected) {
                    Risk cellRisk = getTableRow().getItem();
                    for (Risk risk : getTableView().getItems()) {
                        risk.setDefaultRisk(risk == cellRisk);
                    }
                }
            });
    } else {
        setGraphic(null);
    }
}
```

If you have a lot of table items (like, thousands), the for-loop could become a performance issue.  So, alternatively, you can implement radio-button-like behavior by defining a Risk field or property *independent of the RadioButtonCell class* which keeps track of the previous selection:

```
ObjectProperty<Risk> previousDefaultRisk = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
columnIsDefaultRisk.setCellFactory(
    c -> new RadioButtonCell(previousDefaultRisk));
```

And your RadioButtonCell class would change to look like this:

```
public class RadioButtonCell extends TableCell<Risk, Boolean> {

    private final ObjectProperty<Risk> previousDefaultRisk;

    public RadioButtonCell(ObjectProperty<Risk> previousDefaultRisk) {
        this.previousDefaultRisk = previousDefaultRisk;
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (!empty && item != null) {

            RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
            radioButton.setSelected(item);
            setGraphic(radioButton);

            radioButton.selectedProperty().addListener(
                (o, old, selected) -> {
                    if (selected) {
                        if (previousDefaultRisk.get() != null) {
                            previousDefaultRisk.get().setDefaultRisk(false);
                        }
                        Risk risk = getTableRow().getItem();
                        risk.setIsDefaultRisk(true);
                        previousDefaultRisk.set(risk);
                    }
                });
        } else {
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: It is Java convention that non-static field names should always start with a lowercase letter.  Following these conventions will make your code easier for others to read, including Stack Overflow readers.

Comment: OKAYYYY i now understand why it don't work. I was dubvious about what was wrong in my code. I made a previous test with Listener on radioButton but it created a loop. You really mad my day. About the writing convention, are you talking about the MAJ that I put on the column name ?

Comment: I am talking about ColumnCheckBox, ColumnRiskValue, and ColumnIsDefaultRisk, which should be `columnCheckBox`, `columnRiskValue`, and `columnIsDefaultRisk`, respectively, both in the code and in your .fxml file.